# Playbook AIR SDK images on surface

Tags: apache-flex, image, air, blackberry-playbook

I am trying to write a Playbook app using the AIR SDK, I need a surface of some kind that I can load a large image onto, then subsequently place some smaller images on top of and add the whole lot to a ScrollPane so I can pan it around the screen.

I have tried by adding the image to a sprite and displaying that in a group in the application but the image does not show up.

What is the correct surface kind I should be using here and how should I be loading the images? (currently using "Embed" and loading the image into a BitmapAsset.)

Thanks

EDIT:

```
        var scroll:ScrollPane = new ScrollPane();

        scroll.setScrollContent(image);
        scroll.update();

        scroll.graphics.beginBitmapFill(icon.bitmapData);
        scroll.graphics.drawRect(100,100,56,56);
        scroll.graphics.endFill();

        scroll.update();
```

This code causes a non-moving icon to be drawn *behind* the scrollContent, I want to add something on top of the scroll content that moves with it.

Comment: A group with basic layout should be fine.  Put the background image in the component, defined in your MXML, then add your <s:Image> components after (for correct z-order).  Have you tried this (using components) rather than trying to draw with the graphics api?

Comment: I had a go, yes, the problem I am having is that ScrollPane is a QNX component, and i have problems adding standard components such as  containers to it. I can add an image ok, when I try adding a group, or a sprite I get no display. I need to do it in code too rather than XML definitions because I need to be able to dynamically add icons on top of the image in arbitrary locations at runtime.

Comment: Ok, problem is becoming more clear now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than adding your images via the graphics api, you need to be adding components as I mentioned in the comment.  Now that I know you're trying to use the QNX component set, the situation is a little different.

What you need to do is stick with the QNX components if at all possible otherwise they may not get updated in the display list properly (like things being drawn in the background like you're experiencing)

For the images you should be using something like this :

```
var newImg : qnx.ui.display.Image = new qnx.ui.display.Image();
newImage.setImage( youImgObj );
```

For adding containers like you mentioned, you should be using (or similar) :

```
qnx.ui.core.Container
```

Then you should find things are drawn in a predictable order (last obj added is on top of stage).

Comment: Worked as promised, thanks! I realised when playing that the similarly named QNX APIs are unrelated to the standard ones, in fact they're not even descendant of, and so they don't necessarily function anything like you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Make your own custom component (you can put it on a ScrollPane later) and draw the images yourself -

MyComp.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ViewNavigatorApplication 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    firstView="views.MyCompHomeView">
</s:ViewNavigatorApplication>
```

views\MyCompHomeView.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:comps="comps.*" title="HomeView">
    <comps:MyRect width="100%" height="100%"/>
</s:View>
```

comps\MyRect.mxml (draws a red rectangle with shadow underneath):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:UIComponent xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    width="100%" height="100%">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flash.filters.*;

            public static const SHADOW:Array = [ 
                        new DropShadowFilter(10, 80, 0x000000, 
                        0.5, 32, 32, 1, 1, false, false, false) ];
            public static const GLOW:Array = [ 
                        new GlowFilter(0xFFFF00, 0.5, 
                        36, 36, 1, 1, false, false) ];

            private var rect:Shape = new Shape();

            override protected function createChildren():void {
                super.createChildren();
                rect.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
                rect.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 20, 20);
                rect.filters = SHADOW;
                addChild(rect);
            }

            override protected function updateDisplayList(
                        unscaledWidth:Number,
                        unscaledHeight:Number):void {

                super.updateDisplayList(
                    unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
                rect.x = unscaledWidth / 2;
                rect.y = unscaledHeight / 2;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</mx:UIComponent>
```